# How to output an element only once after array is looped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

So, I have the following code:

```
const arr = ["one", "two"];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${arr[i]}: 1`, `${arr[i]}: 2`);
}
```

I want the output to be,

```
one: 1
two: 2
```

But I get,

```
one: 1
one: 2
two: 1
two: 2
```

How do I get the expected output? Thanks in advance.
NOTE: This is just an example code

Comment: ```console.log(`${arr[i]}: ${i + 1}`);```?

Comment: `console.log(\`${arr[i]}: ${i+1}\`);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = ["one", "two"];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${arr[i]}: ${i +1}`);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Or even easier
`["one", "two"].forEach((item, index) => console.log(\`${item}: ${index + 1}\`))`

Comment: What would i do if instead of integers there are strings in the output, eg  ```one: apples two: bananas```

Comment: ${i} directly .